# Laravel 5.2 - How to set random id for Eloquent table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a test table :

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('besttts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('id')->primary()->index();
        $table->string('tests')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

How i can make the 'id' not to be increment and autofilled?

Comment: Migration you showed doesn't use `increments()` on `primary()` so why do you think it's autoincremented?

Comment: it's just an a example....

Comment: Your example contains what your question is about. Why do you ask first before trying out your own code?

Comment: I try this example and it's still not work

Comment: `not work` means nothing to anyone, we can't read your mind. Example in question makes `id` a primary key that isn't autoincremented, that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create `id` column:

```
$table->integer('id');
```

And then set primary key in the model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
public $incrementing = false;
```

Or you could try to create `id` as usual:

```
$table->increments('id');
```

And then just set `$incrementing` to `false`:

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

> If you wish to use a non-incrementing or a non-numeric primary key you must set the public `$incrementing` property on your model to false.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#defining-models

Comment: The id is incrementing when i try the second option you offer

Comment: The first option return 0 as id to all new record

Comment: @DaniBanai isn't this what you want? I thought you want to set up ID manually.